# How to import json and urllib on jsp files

Tags: python, jsp

Hi all (sorry for my poor English langages)

I want to create a .jsp files who call a python script (the python script makes an update on a cache geographic information system, and the script works when i use it with python idle)

but when i call it from my jsp pages, he does not work.

error send to me is :

can't import json, urllib2 etc... etc...

Please help me.

**EDIT 1**

i have one jsp page like that :

```
<%@ page import="org.python.core.*" %> 
<%@ page import="org.python.core.PyInteger" %> 
<%@ page import="org.python.core.PyObject" %> 
<%@ page import="org.python.util.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page import="javax.script.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.lang.Object" %> 
<pre>
```

Comment: Can you do `print(__import__)` and `print(__builtins__)` and `print(__builtin__)` and paste the output (not in IDLE)? These influence the import behaviour.

Comment: Thank's for answer. (i see the light !!!)
In IDLE i print the __import__ and __builtins__ and __builtin__ i have the specific path of my python librairy so i need what i need to do ?

May i can show my problem code.

Comment: i have one jsp pages like that :

<%@ page import="org.python.core.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.python.core.PyInteger" %>
<%@ page import="org.python.core.PyObject" %>
<%@ page import="org.python.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.script.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.lang.Object" %> 
<pre>

Comment: <%    
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); //ouput will be stored here
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();
    context.setWriter(writer); //configures output redirection
  
  try{
  
   ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
   engine.eval(new FileReader("c:\\repert.py"), context);
   out.println(writer.toString());
   
  } catch (ScriptException e){
  
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  }
  
%>

Comment: and my python like that :

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import os
from os.path import join

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

#liste l'ensemble des fichiers et repertoires d'un repertoire.
 
print "<h1>Liste dossier et repertoire</h1>\n"
print "<table>\n"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\folder'):
    print "<tr>"
    print "<td>"+root+"</td>"
    print "</tr>\n"
  
  
print "</table>\n"

Comment: when i execute it, i have no error. and nothing on screen. When i use (ctrl+u) i see only that  <pre></pre>

Comment: So if i use my map cached server python script i have the same problem nothing on screen ((

Comment: You should put that code formatted into the question, not in the comments. Delete the comments after this - this way you get a good question. Use the {}Bottom.

Comment: Looking at your code: You do java imports in it. Python imports may not work the same way as Java imports. Python imports happen in the Python language after the script is started. There you should be able to use `import urllib` in the Python code.